# django create super user command

Tags: django, django-users

[Cmd pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKXQO.png)

[Cmd 2 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DP8j0.png)

[Cmd 3 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7xDZ.png)
[Cmd5 pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liAf2.png)

hello , I had tried to use the createsuperuser command, it did not work, please can u help? The pics show the steps i used on windows cmd . I would have written it in text but its was not getting copied. Sorry, if  u are not supposed to ask these easy qustions.

Comment: Please copy/paste the text directly into your question rather than posting screenshots.

Comment: Also be sure to read the entire error message. It tells you exactly what to do.

Comment: first apply your unapplied migrations. I think auth_user table is not created.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Its solved already. Thank you for ur trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**step 1**

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

**step 2**

```
python manage.py migrate
```

**step 3**

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you to migrate your changes. It even gave you the command to run.

```
python manage.py migrate
```